# Validations that rely on associations being built in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

A `Course` has many `Lessons`, and they are chosen by the user with a JS drag-n-drop widget which is working fine.

Here's the relevant part of the params when I choose two lessons:

```
Parameters: {
  "course_lessons_attributes"=>[
    {"lesson_id"=>"43", "episode"=>"1"}, 
    {"lesson_id"=>"44", "episode"=>"2"}
  ]
}
```

I want to perform some validations on the `@course` and it's new set of lessons, including how many there are, the sum of the lessons' prices and other stuff. Here's a sample:

**Course Model**

```
validate :contains_lessons
def contains_lessons
  errors[:course] << 'must have at least one lesson' unless lessons.any?
end
```

My problem is that the associations between the course and the lessons are not yet built before the course is saved, and that's when I want to call upon them for my validations (using `course.lessons`).

What's the correct way to be performing custom validations that rely on associations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the `course.lessons`, but the `course_lessons` are there, so I ended up doing something like this in the validation method to get access to the array of lessons.

```
def custom validation
  val_lessons = Lesson.find(course_lessons.map(&:lesson_id))
  # ...
  # check some things about the associated lessons and add errors 
  # ...
end
```

I'm still open to there being a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you don't need a custom validation here, consider using this one:

```
validates :lessons, :presence => true
```

or

```
validates :lessons, :presence => {:on => :create}
```

Comment: You're correct about that particular validation, but unfortunately there are others which require me to iterate over the collection of lessons. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, while implementing this I learned that you actually need to validate the presence of :course_lessons rather than just :lessons.

Comment: yes, sure, course_lessons if the association is :course_lessons :) I just said lessons because of this checking `unless lessons.any?` - i thought lessons is the actual association name